# Create Library in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

How do we create a library in Simulink ? I created a library for my project. But I am not sure how to use the blocks defined in the library in my project ?

Should all the blocks be masked subsystem in the library ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use File -> New -> Library to create the library. Then any subsystem you put in the library can be used as a link in your model.  The subsystem does not have to be masked.

To use one, just drag the subsystem from the library into your model, and it will automatically create a link.